# Regex with OR operator not catching "double" matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Using PHP's `preg_match_all` I have the following problem.

Example string:

```
last_name, first_name
bjorge, philip
sdfsdf credit note dfsdf
kardashian, kim
mercury, freddie
```

Regex:

```
/\bcredit\b|\bcredit note\b|\bfreddie\b/
```

Current Result:

```
array(1
  0 =>  array(2
    0   =>  credit
    1   =>  freddie
  )
)
```

Expected result:

```
array(1
  0 =>  array(3
    0   =>  credit
    1   =>  credit note
    2   =>  freddie
  )
)
```

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/GeW#tab-preg-match-all

Probably a very common problem, but I was not able to find a solution.

Comment: You should put the longer patterns first. If you build the regex dynamically, sort the options by descending length dynamically before creating the regex from them.

Comment: @trincot I was also thinking about this, but it's not ideal. I still wont know a have a match on  'credit'.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, and my keywords in the regex are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can not revisit the same position twice to match the same string.

What you can do is put them in a lookahead with a capture group and make the `credit`  part optional

```
$re = '/\b(?=((?:credit )?note|freddie)\b)/';
$str = 'last_name, first_name
bjorge, philip
sdfsdf credit note dfsdf
kardashian, kim
mercury, freddie';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "credit note"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "note"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "freddie"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in my case the keywords are dynamic. You gonna have endless combinations.

Comment: @RUijl Where are the keywords coming from? You could dynamically generate a non capture group like `(?:keyword1|keyword2)` using an array and implode for example.

Answer (score -2):

```
last_name, first_name
bjorge, philip
credit <-----  ;)
sdfsdf credit note dfsdf
kardashian, kim
mercury, freddie
```

change the input.

regex will match once, so based on your result you need to take into account that "credit note" contains "credit". maybe use preg_quote() if you are working in php.

Comment: This is not an answer lol

Comment: I think the only other way to do this is if you do this in a loop name by name.